# displaying different texts on different button clicks in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I am making a user interactive selection system using unity where, there are buttons denoting various products and the product name is to be displayed in a systematic order one below the other when the user clicks on the product. I have used OnGUI() function for  the display of product name. But on my output, all the names are getting printed super imposed over one another.

I tied increment the y positions of the GUI.label using static variable i (defined to 0 initially). I tried increment the value of i on every click and add it to the  y position of  the GUI.label. Now when i click the second button both the first button label and second button label move to the new co ordinates.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;// 1
using UnityEngine.UI;

``public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler // 2

// ... And many more available!
{
    SpriteRenderer sprite;
    Color target = Color.red;
    int a=200,b=100;

    public GUIText textObject;
    public bool showGUI;
    public int s=0;



    public static int i=0;



    void Awake()
    {
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void test()
    {
        i = i + 20;

        OnGUI();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (sprite)
            sprite.color = Vector4.MoveTowards(sprite.color, target, Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData) // 3
    {
        showGUI = true;
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
        target = Color.blue;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("Display", gameObject.name);
        s = 1;
        test ();


    }

    void OnGUI()
    {

        if (s == 1) {

            GUI.color = Color.red;
            GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle (GUI.skin.GetStyle ("label"));
            myStyle.fontSize = 20;

            GUI.Label (new Rect (a, b, 100f, 10f), "");

            if (showGUI) {

                //GUI.Box (new Rect (a,b+i, 300f, 100f), "");
                GUI.Label (new Rect (a, b + i, 300f, 100f), gameObject.name, myStyle);

                s = 0;
            }


        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **[not](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html)** use the `OnGUI()` function. It is intended as a tool for programmers and not as a UI that will be running in your game. . Here is a simple Button and Button click detector in Unity.

Let's say you need two Buttons, the example below will show how to do that:

First, create two Buttons:

**GameObject**->**UI**->**Button**.

Secondly, include the `UnityEngine.UI;` namespace with `using UnityEngine.UI;`.

Declare the `Buttons` variables:

```
public Button button1;
public Button button2;
```

Create a callback function that will be called when the each `Button` is clicked:

```
private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    if (buttonPressed == button1)
    {
        //Your code for button 1
    }

    if (buttonPressed == button2)
    {
        //Your code for button 2
    }
}
```

Connect the `Buttons` to that callback function(Register Button events) when Script is enabled.

```
void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
    button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));
}
```

Disconnect the `Buttons` to from that callback function(Un-register Button events) when Script is disabled.

```
void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    button2.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

To Modify the Text attached to the Button:

```
button1.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Hello1";
button2.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Hello2";
```

You use `GetComponentInChildren` because the `Text` created is made to be a child of each Button. I don't think I can make this easier to understand. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) is a tutorial for Unity UI.